# Как из .bat файла запустить другой с правами администратора?

Tags: bat

Возможно ли запустить из .bat файла другой файл с правами администратора? ***runas*** не подходит для этих целей, т.к. запуск из под аккаунта администратора не эквивалентен  запуску от имени администратора.

Comment: Почему это не подоходит? runas как раз для этого предназначен.

Comment: дело в том, что как я понял runas запускает файл под именем определенного пользователя, у которого могут быть выставлены определенные права. Правами администратора на разных компьютерах могут обладать разные пользователи с разными именами. Вопрос заключается в том, можно ли вызвать файл с правами администратора без привязки к имени аккаунта, обладающего ими

Comment: Понял. Нужно как-то получить имя пользователя, обладающего админскими правами и подставить его в runas.

Comment: Я думал, думал... Получить список админов несложно. Потом подставить любого из них в runas. Но их может быть несколько. Какого именно подставлять? Ведь система потом запросит пароль. А знает ли текущий пользователь пароль именно от этого аккаунта-админа? Так что самое логичное - пусть пользователь сам запускает батник из-под админа: он-то знает, какого именно выбрать.

Comment: Да, на эти же самые проблемы наткнулся и я пока думал над этим вопросом. Поэтому и сформулировал другой, возможно ли как-нибудь вызвать файл с правами администратора без привязки к имени аккаунта, обладающего ими. Может это можно как-то сделать не средствами batch?

Comment: Обойти UAC невозможно. Система потребует ввода пароля. Пароля от того или иного аккаунта. Поэтому пусть пользователь сам запускает из-под того акка, от которого знает пароль.

Comment: Спасибо, просто оставлю заметку как пользователь может сделать такой bat под себя и свою систему